# Linux Kernel TCP Socket modification

Tags: sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

Is there is any easy way to modify tcp socket parameters?
For example:
Server_program is using eth0 with 10.0.0.1, it can't be restarted and I need to recreate socket on the eth1 with 192.168.0.1. I know there is some other not trival problems but all I'm looking now is possibility to modify socket "on-the-fly" inside the kernel.
Thank you for any advices.

Comment: The program's hardcoded to the 10.x IP? I doubt you could modify a socket in-memory to change its port/ip like that, short of being Linus, but perhaps the iptables stuff can internally do a redirect for you.

Comment: Marc B:
But program connects with inode. Right? I need put program "on hold", modify socket informations and run program

Answer (score 2):

Open the new socket, do whatever steps are needed to get it connected and into the same state, and then use [dup2()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) to turn the old file descriptor into a clone of the new one.

Comment: ...and if you want to do this from outside, you can use `ptrace()` to debauch the target process as necessary.